# get sum over the distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get the sum of column c on distinct id for a particular project
below is the table

```
+---------+----+----+-----+
| Project | ID |  C |  D  |
+---------+----+----+-----+
| A       | 1  | 10 |  1  |
+---------+----+----+-----+
| B       | 2  | 20 |  2  |
+---------+----+----+-----+
| A       | 1  | 10 |  3  |
+---------+----+----+-----+
| A       | 3  | 30 |  4  |
+---------+----+----+-----+
```

i want to get as below output:

```
+---------+----+
| Project |  C |
+---------+----+
| A       | 40 |
+---------+----+
| B       | 20 |
+---------+----+
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sub-query with `distinct` to find unique record & do aggregation :

```
select project, sum(c) as c
from (select distinct project, id, c 
      from table t
     ) t
group by project;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply aggregation and grouping twice. In the subquery, nest `distinct` within the `sum()` aggregation

```
SELECT project, sum(sum_C) as sum_C
  FROM
  (
   SELECT project, sum(distinct C) as sum_C
     FROM tab
    GROUP BY ID, project
   ) q
 GROUP BY project
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=fb52fbc2756420a85eeb7c509dce3b81)</kbd>

Comment: Brain fart, ignore me. :)

Comment: :) doesn't matter @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
select t.project, sum(t.c) as c
from (
 select project, c, id
 from t
 group by project, c, id
) t
group by t.project
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using GROUP BY:

SELECT Project, SUM(C)
FROM table
GROUP BY Project

Comment: That returns 50 for the A project, instead of 40, as he says he wants.

Comment: @chaitanyadalvi then would would the OP state *"i want to get the sum of column c on **distinct** id for a particular project below is the table"*?